# TalkBack won't turn off

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, talk-back

I have a Motorola Moto E running KitKat 4.4.4. It somehow got into TalkBack mode and now I can't swipe the screen to get into Settings. I did a factory reset, but it's still there! How can I change the settings when I can't get to them?

Answer (score 1):

If you have inadvertently enabled Talkback, you can quickly pause it then go to the Settings and disable this feature.

- From anywhere on the screen, swipe down then right in a single motion, as if you were drawing an “L”.
  *(This should work whether the phone is on the lock screen or unlocked.)*
- You will then see 2 options in the top corners of the screen, select “Pause Feedback”.
- When the **Suspend Talkback** message appears, double tap “OK”.
- You can now normally go into  *Settings > Accessibility* and disable Talkback.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the UP and DOWN volume buttons for 3 seconds, then do it AGAIN.